# How do i avoid running out of memory when performing a task on every item of core data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, memory

I'm trying to perform a task similar to this:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Entry"];

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(version == %@)", @"1.0"];

        [request setPredicate:predicate];

        NSArray *results = [[AppDelegate applicationDelegate].managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];

int i = 0;

        while (i < results.count) {

            Entry *entry = [results objectAtIndex:i];

            entry.version = @"1.1";

            i++;
        }
```

But it runs out of memory before it's got through every result.

I'm aware of this:

```
[request setFetchBatchSize:20];
```

But I'm wondering how that would work with what I have? Would it stop processing after 20 results, or would it just grab the first 20 results then somehow grab the next 20 and continue?

What i'm asking essentially is how do i only grab a certain amount of data, to stop it running out of memory, then grab another batch?

Comment: Have you tried `[context save:&error]; [context reset];` every N = ??? items? That should turn all modified objects into faults again and release the memory. (Perhaps combined with an autorelease pool inside the loop.)

Answer (score 0):

You guessed right. You have to use `setFetchBatchSize:`. This will only return the first 20 objects. If you want to get the next 20 objects, you have to set the offset using [`setFetchOffset:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFetchRequest/setFetchOffset%3a).

Comment: Alright, thanks. How would you recommend I continue until I've been through every result using setFetchOffset?

Comment: I've been thinking about that. I don't know what's the best way to do that. You could get the number of objects by calling [`countForFetchRequest:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/countForFetchRequest:error:) and then increasing the offset until you reach the end.

Comment: Or you could simply keep executing your request until it returns nil or an empty array meaning that you reached the end.

Comment: Sounds good to me. If I'm simply adding data 1 by one, and it runs out of memory and crashes after a while, despite constantly saving, what's the solution to that?

Comment: Is there a way of sort of releasing the first batch, to say I don't want them now? Or will ARC do that automatically meaning i don't have to worry about them taking up memory?

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect case for using an `@autoreleasepool`

Place an @autoreleasepool around all the code which gets executed in your loop. This will automatically release the objects after they get processed so your memory footprint stays low. If using this technique you shouldn't have to specify a batch size.

See the apple docs here for more information;

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html

Comment: I just tried this. It crashed at around the same point. Thanks though.

Comment: Can you post some of your code to do that? So your getting memory warnings? Are you testing on the device or simulator?

Comment: On the device. I'm not getting any memory warnings. It just crashes to the home screen, with no error in the log.

Comment: Hmm, it definitely could be memory. I would profile with Instuments using the allocations tool just to be sure.

Comment: http://cl.ly/image/0R321v1N2t3v This is a screenshot of after running the allocations tool on code which added a large number of entries to my core data.